# how many units must you have lost to access the optional chapters in Fire Emblem: Shadow Dragon?

Tags: fire-emblem-shadow-dragon

I've heard that there are some chapters in shadow dragon that can only be accessed if you have a certain number of units or less, which usually means killing off units. how many units must you have lost to get these chapters, if there are any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the wiki list of chapters](https://fireemblem.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_chapters_in_Fire_Emblem:_Shadow_Dragon), there a total of 5 chapters that can only accessed based on the available units. These chapters are noted as "Chapter NX"

1. [Chapter 6x](https://fireemblem.fandom.com/wiki/In_War%27s_Grip)

   > To advance to this chapter, the number of alive units must be 15 or less by the end of Chapter 6.
2. [Chapter 12x](https://fireemblem.fandom.com/wiki/A_Traitor%27s_Worth)

   > To gain access to this chapter, complete Chapter 12: The Ageless Palace with 15 units or less.
3. [Chapter 17x](https://fireemblem.fandom.com/wiki/Helena_Castle)

   > To gain access to this chapter, finish Chapter 17 with 15 units or fewer alive.
4. [Chapter 20x](https://fireemblem.fandom.com/wiki/The_Lair_of_Fire)

   > To advance to this chapter, complete Chapter 20: Camus the Sable with 15 or fewer units alive
5. [Chapter 24x](https://fireemblem.fandom.com/wiki/The_Alterspire)

   > If you want to advance to this Gaiden Chapter you must have Tiki dead (or not recruited) and the Falchion not in possession by the end of chapter 24

Comment: how would you not kill, but not recruit Tiki considering she's on the throne?

Comment: @BlazingTrio. Wondercricket meant you can either fail to recruit her (by killing her), or lose her to the enemy (after recruiting her). As a side note, you must also choose not to obtain Falchion. As it has unlimited use, you cannot break it or get rid of it once you have it. Also keep in mind that while you'll receive another Falchion in 24x, it'll be a weaker version of the one you've missed.